# Which virtual machine OS do I need?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

My VM is described in Azure variously as "A Series Basic Windows" and "A0" and "Windows (Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter)". It costs about $13/month.

Awhile back, Azure said I'd have to migrate to a newer OS. Haven't heard anything about it since. My needs are quite basic. Scarcely any activity. Wonder if/when I'll be forced to upgrade, and what the cost will be, and how to contain the cost?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: Why be so narrowminded? The Azure environment actually directs users to StackOverflow to seek answers for questions that necessarily are about the Azure environment and not about programming. If you are a developer like me, you surely realize how much time we spend dealing with networking issues, IDE updates, server configurations and on and on, versus doing what we love -- coding. StackOverflow is the very place where users might have useful ideas and experience about Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the VM that you use is determined by the workload that you want to run. Azure offers a wide variety of sizes to support many types of uses.

Azure charges an hourly price based on the VM’s size and operating system type.

For pricing estimations of the VM, I recommend to use Azure Calculator. Here's the link for it. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/